# Percorrer string e substituir um caractere específico

Tags: php, string

Queria substituir, numa *string*, todas as ocorrências do carácter `&` por um `e` (ou removê-lo). O caractere pode estar no meio de uma palavra ou aparecer várias vezes na mesma string.

Exemplo:

> Valor original: O João foi ao Hotel & Spa passar férias.
>
> Após substituição: O João foi ao Hotel e Spa passar férias.

Comment: E quer o resultado corrigido numa variável ou quer substituir na base de dados?

Comment: @Sergio quero o resultado numa variável

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Pode usar o [str_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), os parametros dessa função são:

> #### str_replace(procurar, substituto, origem, $ocorrencias)
>
> **procurar** - o texto a procurar
>    **substituto** - o texto que deve substituir o que for encontrado em *procurar*
>    **origem** - a string onde está o conteúdo a ser substituído
>    **$ocorrencias** *(opcional)* - esta variável vai receber o valor de quantas vezes o replace foi executado e o texto encontrado/substituído.

Um exemplo seria:

```
$string = "O João foi ao Hotel & Spa passar férias";
$stringCorrigida = str_replace('&', 'e', $string);
echo $stringCorrigida; // resultado: O João foi ao Hotel e Spa passar férias
```

Comment: É isso mesmo. Obrigado @Sergio

Comment: @pc_oc ótimo. Fico contente de ter ajudado.

Comment: Que estranho que está solução não se aplica a esta pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54541/como-posso-converter-estas-strings-no-php ... será que é por causa que o str_replace está tendo problemas com os caracteres?

Comment: Sérgio, e no caso da ocorrência for qualquer valor dentro de um array? Como se faz isso?

Comment: @DiChrist podes dar um exemplo?

Comment: Sim. Por exemplo, se num texto eu tenho várias ocorrências da tag <br />, e quero fazer com que se nesse texto tiver com 3 ou mais tags <br /> seguidas sejam substituídas por uma só, eu não teria que usar o array para deixar essas ocorrências gravadas e usar esse array no replace?

Comment: @DiChrist acho que seria melhor colocar uma pergunta separada, nesse caso acho que o melhor seria CSS.

Answer (score 2):

A solução com função pronta é adequada, mas complemento fazendo diretamente com um `for` para as pessoas entenderem o mecanismo que está ocorrendo dentro da função.

E a solução do `for` passa ser mais adequada quando tem mais do que uma letra que deve ser trocada, seja por outras ou por uma única, ou ainda se tiver uma regra um pouco mais complicada. Porque se rodar o `str_replace()` várias vezes para cada letra começa ficar ineficiente e o código fica mais longo do que fazendo um laço manualmente. Então fica aqui uma alternativa para quem está aprendendo a programar agora e ainda não percebe quando algo pode ser bom em um contexto e ruim em outro.

```
<?php
$string = "O João foi ao Hotel & Spa passar férias";
$stringCorrigida = "";
$stringLength = strlen($string);
for ($i = 0; $i < $stringLength; $i++) $stringCorrigida .= ($string[$i] == '&' ? 'e' : $string[$i]);
echo $stringCorrigida;
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/String/ReplaceFor.php). E [no **repl.it**](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/String/ReplaceFor.php). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/String/ReplaceFor.php).