# Como posso converter estas strings no PHP?

Tags: php, xml, codificação-de-caracteres

Tenho as seguintes instruções ....

```
echo $parcelamento . "<br>"; 
echo utf8_encode($parcelamento) . "<br>";
echo utf8_decode($parcelamento) . "<br>";
```

... que retornam respectivamente isso:

```
ou 12x de R$ 21,58 sem juros no cartÃÂÃÂ£o
ou 12x de R$ 21,58 sem juros no cartÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂ£o
ou 12x de R$ 21,58 sem juros no cartÃÂ£o
```

Alguém consegue me dizer como vou retornar o termo ***cartão***?

Outra solução seria substituir ***cartÃƒÂƒÃ‚Â£o*** por ***cartão*** dentro da frase proposta mas não sei desenvolver nenhuma das soluções.

Estou executando um ***PHP*** para esse ***[XML](http://stanley.axitech.com.br/wp-content/themes/ead/xml/equipamentos.xml)***

Comment: Você definiu o *charset* para utf-8? assim: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />`.

Comment: estranho... Provavelmente $parcelamento já vem corrompido. linha 1 (4*utf8); linha 2 (5*utf8); linha 3 (3*utf8). Como sugeriu @Qmechanic73; o encoding errado pode corrigir um (2*utf8) -- o problema deve vir de trás.

Comment: Como você está obtendo e "parseando" esse XML?

Comment: Sugiro que edite a pergunta e adicione a origem dos dados tal como qual o encode/charset dos mesmos. do jeito como está, vamos apenas ficar chutando alguma possibilidade..   improdutivo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função `utf8_encode()` deveria ser chamada de `iso88591_to_utf8()` para não confundir tanto.

No seu caso, você não precisa usar esta função, pois seus dados já estão em UTF-8. É bom deixar seus dados em UTF-8, como você já faz, até o último possível momento.

Para ter certeza de não "poluir" seu ambiente XML e evitar conversões acidentais, declare seu HTML como UTF-8 também, conforme a sugestão de @qmechanik:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Seu XML já está identificado explicitamente como UTF-8:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```